# Cannot send multiple bytes data in TCP sampler [Apache Jmeter]

Tags: java, node.js, sockets, tcp, jmeter

I'm trying to load test a Node.js TCP server using Apache Jmeter. I've created a TCP sampler to simulate virtual users for the TCP servers and currently testing with 10 threads. The data that I'm sending to the TCP server contains location information in bytes.

Each location packet contains same start bits and same end bits. I split the bytes string according to the end bits inside the the Beanshell Preprocessor script. When I try to send the data to the server, each thread only send the first location packet and discards the rests.

This is the location data that I'm sending to the TCP Server:

> 78782222110c0f080428c70312a7b0084b69f000153d01940b03f800e0110102010005462c0d0a
>   78782222110c0f081a39c90312af68084b83f010140f01940b03f80045580100000016b5830d0a
>   78782222110c0f081b2ac90312bacc084b87800b140d01940b03f80045590100000020bc450d0a
>   78782222110c0f081c04c80312bf2c084b83b017151a01940b03f8004559010000002735860d0a
>   78782222110c0f081c13c90312bf58084b7cb017150101940b03f800f26e010000002a5ea20d0a
>   78782222110c0f081e0eca0312a788084b6cd00c151e01940b03f800455801000000419fd30d0a

Script for BeanShell Preprocessor:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.*;

String textToSend = "";
String fLine = "";

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("${fname}");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    while((fLine = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
        textToSend = textToSend + fLine;
    }

String[] list = textToSend.split("0d0a");

for (String str : list) {
    sampler.setRequestData(str);
}
```

Comment: why don't you send sampler.setRequestData(textToSend)?

Comment: @user7294900 it will send the whole data in one go but I have to send it in packets. It's like different users sending different lcoations.